cannot configure WiFi network on octopi/raspberry pi neither dhcp nor static ip
I have tried to connect my raspberry 3B via WiFi, but get an error as follows:

dhcpcd failed on all interfaces "not configured"
/etc/dhcpcd.conf configured for static IP on wlan0: no IPv4 address available
octopi-wpa-supplicant.txt configured for WiFi network SSID: dhcpcd error
https://community.octoprint.org/t/wifi-setup-and-troubleshooting/184

What else could I possibly configure to get WiFi networking starting up?

Are you sure that your interface are configured to receive the DHCP ? Does your DHCP have adress available ?

DHCP on the fritz.box works fine. I configured /etc/network/interfaces for DHCP, I think I will try static configuration here, too!

I happen to have a static IP on the raspberry/octopi now via /etc/network/interfaces. But the Pi is not pingeable: I think the WiFi SSID/key is not logged in correct. Anybody an idea on how to do that?

I made an octoprint backup! Now I consider installing octopi new and restoring the backup: any objections?

Is your raspberry suppose to get the ip from the DHCP ? did you make a reservation for it ? I have no objection on reinstalling the octopi
